# on click i want to generate alert in react js method

Tags: reactjs

This is my code:

```
generateAlert = () => {
    alert('hi');
}

return <Tile
    click={(index)=>{this.generateAlert}}
    title={tile.title} 
    value={tile.value}
    key={tile.id}
/>
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
>   Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Did you search for the error like the error message tells you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I do wonder if in your Component you have an array of `Tile` data, and you want to render a `Tile` for each entry of the array (I thought so because you added the `key` prop to `Tile`).

Anyways, I made an example similar to what you want to achieve, and it's working. Look at this:

```js
const Tile = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="Tile">
            <h3>{props.title}</h3>
            <div onClick={props.click}>
                {props.value}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    
    generateAlert = () => {
        alert("Hi");
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <Tile
                click={this.generateAlert}
                title={"This isa a Title"}
                value={"This is the value"} />
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Now, I may help you in a deeper way if you would post the code of the Component that wants to render `Tile`; maybe, there are some error in that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jolly

Comment: You're welcome. Though, if you did fix the problem (you said that no alert was shown), explain what was the error: future users may end up here and need that piece of information :)

Answer (score 1):

Hei!

If it's a function invocation inside your component's `onClick` function, you need to add `()` after `this.generateAlert` in your component

So it's gonna be like:

```
return <Tile
  click={(index)=>{this.generateAlert()}}
  title={tile.title} 
  value={tile.value}
  key={tile.id}
/>
```

Otherwise, you can use your function as a `onClick` callback per se.

In that case you need to have it like this:

```
return <Tile
  onClick={this.generateAlert}
  title={tile.title} 
  value={tile.value}
  key={tile.id}
/>
```

Cheers!

Comment: What exactly is `Tile`? Because the second example should work if you write `onClick` instead of `click`

Comment: const tile = (props) => {

    return (
        <div className="Tile"> 
            <h3>{props.title}</h3>
            <div  onClick={props.click}>
                {props.value}
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
    );
};

Answer (score 0):

I will do in this way:

> Q: why I export Tile to new component?
>
> A: As each component should be as short as possible. There is a many advantages to doing in this way
> like: "easy to find bugs (testing)".

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Tile from "./Tile";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.generateAlert = this.generateAlert.bind(this);
  }

  generateAlert = () => {
    alert("Hi");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Tile
        click={this.generateAlert}
        title={"This isa a Title"}
        value={"This is the value"}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and file Tile.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Tile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.click}>click me</button>
        <p>{this.props.title}</p>
        <p>{this.props.value}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This file Tile.js are ready for future addons but if you want to use only like it is now I would recommend to change into stateless component:

```
import React from "react";

const Tile = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={props.click}>click me</button>
      <p>{props.title}</p>
      <p>{props.value}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tile;
```